# ImageResizer and VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, imageresizer

I have a project that was created using Visual Studio 2015.
These projects don't use web.configs to my knowledge.
Having uses ImageResizer before, I wanted to use it in this project but because there is no web.config I can't get it to work

Has anyone used ImageResizer in a VS 2015 project? If so, how did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also curious to know if there's a way to use ImageResizer with ASP.NET 5 and the new web.config-less project structure. [Nathanel Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166893/nathanael-jones) should know the answer.