# Does ImageResizer with PdfRenderer work in asp.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, imageresizer

I can get the image conversion working in asp.NET 5 beta 7 with manual set up as suggested in the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188162/imageresizer-and-vs-2015), when I convert from image to image. However, when I try to use the Pdf Renderer Plugin, it will throw an exception when trying to load the ghost script library.

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in ImageResizer.dll
>
> Additional information: Ghostscript native library for this platform not found: gsdll64.dll

The same scenario works fine in an asp.NET 4.5.x web site so I'm wondering if there using image resizer with the pdf renderer in an asp.NET 5 web site is currently a dead end due to native assembly loading issues? (I've seen a few GitHub issues in asp.NET 5 as well as repositories from [Imazen](https://github.com/imazen/Graphics-vNext) that makes me believe that this might be the case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency loading is a hopeless disaster right now in .NET. They spurned every possible x-plat solution, and left us in a dead end.

You might try P/Invoking LoadLibrary on gsdll64.dll before you call ImageResizer. This will work on a single platform (win64).

I don't think I will be supporting ASP.NET 5 until it approaches technical preview quality (the 'beta' label is strictly absurd).

Comment: is there an updated timeline on when we can expect imageresizer to work on .net 5 / mvc 6?